# Google and bing spider crawling useless URLs

Tags: magento-1.9

After upgrading my site from magento 1.938 to 1.942, google and bing spiders began crawling useless URLs such as

> https://www.example.com/cms/index/noCookies/

and

> https://www.example.com/wishlist/index/add/product/101/form_key/QRh31BjtGTfy2Ur9

[image]

Google and bing are crawling these URLs in large numbers, and they have never stopped, which consumes a lot of server resources.

I have added the following command to `robots.txt` a long time ago.

```
Disallow: /cms/ 

Disallow: /wishlist/
```

But this seems to be useless.

Before I upgraded to magento 1.942, I never found out that google and bing spiders would crawl these URLs in `Online Customer` tab.

Why is this happening, how to prohibit the crawl of these two URLs?

I have checked the robots.txt in google robots.txt Tester. There is no error in my robots.txt

robots.txt Tester showed these two URLS has been blocked.

Here's screenshot [image]

Comment: Did you check your robots.txt using Google's Search Console? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

you can just block these locations from bots with user agent filter:

```
location ~ ^/(wishlist|customer|catalog/product_compare|tag/product/list|cms/index/noCookies)  {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "Baiduspider|Googlebot|bingbot|rogerbot|Yahoo|Yandex") { return 410; }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

add any location.